# how to check in code whether an external storage device is read only

Tags: android, sd-card, readonly

In my android app I write some files to SD card.
However there is a condition that if the SD card is READ-ONLY
then I have to change screen settings accordingly.
How can I check it in my code if a SD card is read only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) as:

```
String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (status.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "SD MEDIA_MOUNTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY", 
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And more full answer...

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;

}
else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
//    check_folder();
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;

}
```